# float unusual behaviour Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

I am getting an unusal issue with **float** in Objective C. I enter **100.1**  and i get **100.100002** shouldn't it be something like **100.100000** .

Following is the code

```
float temp=100.1;
NSLog(@"%f",temp); 

100.100000
```

Can someone guide me what am i doing wrong or how to fix it ? I cannot use fixed decimal places i-e i cannot just use **100.10** . I need all decimal places .

Comment: The summary of the floating-point tag says “If your question is about small arithmetic or decimal conversion errors, please read the "learn more..." page linked below”. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point

Comment: You should never use float until you can tell us a good reason why you are not using double.

Comment: @gnasher729 - And you should never use double until you know what "floating point" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is a fundamental part of what happens when you represent an arbitrary [floating point value](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) in binary. The number of binary digits is limited, therefore rounding occurs. Depending on your needs, you might be better off using `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `double` instead;

```
double temp=100.1;
NSLog(@"%.8f",temp);

100.10000000
```

It is an issue with representation accuracy. I do not think it will be a problem to use `double` instead.